# How to export Memoji Avatar in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, mac, big-sur

I use Memoji avatar in my iPhone X that shows up in my Mac as well (running Big Sur).

It is showing as the user avatar.

Is there any way to export it or find its local location so that I can use it anywhere I want?

A local PNG or SVG or any other format?